# Dynamically send data and receive data in jQuery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am using jQuery's autocomplete plugin to fill the textbox element. I want the data to be coming from an API call whenever a word is entered in the textbox. There is no predefined array to be passed to the autocomplete function, its dynamically generated from a PHP script.
The code that I am using,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#textbox").autocomplete("myurl.php");
});
```

the PHP script takes a key(i.e `$__GET['key']`) as response value, and on the basis of that queries the database an gives a JSON out put.

But this is not working, how can I send the key value to the PHP script and get the JSON return value and populate my autocomplete element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this page: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions, your PHP script needs to take `$_GET['p']` as the input text and `$_GET['limit']` as the max number of entries. If I understand correctly, your script is looking for the 'key' parameter, when it should be looking for the 'p' parameter.

It also says that the response should be each word on a new line, so rather than passing as JSON, you would need to `echo "$word\n";` for each word from your database.

Alternatively, if you're set on using JSON, you could load the data using something like the following JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getData( keyTxt ) {
    // Send GET request through AJAX
    $.get( 'myurl.php',
           // Set up your query params
           {key:keyTxt},
           // Callback for when the datais returned
           function( data ) {
            // Assuming your PHP puts returns JSON containing the "txt" array
            // Convert the array of words into a space-delimited string
            completeData = data.txt.join( ' ' );
            // Run autocomplete.
            $('textbox#textboxID').autocomplete( completeData )
           },
           // Tell JQuery you're returning json
           'json');
</script>
```

Your PHP would take in the 'key' parameter, query your database and then use `json_encode( )` on the array of words called 'txt'.

Comment: @ianhales i have passed the keyword throught query string manually(i.e myurl.php?key=php), it returns a JSON, but it is not able to populate the autocomplete element.

Comment: I'm not sure that's a very clean way to do it. Have you checked what your PHP is outputting if you go to the url in your browser and put in your query value by hand? Something like `var_dump( $arr )` or `print_r( $arr )` would print the array/object you're getting out. Also, the AFAIK "autocomplete" doesn't accept JSON as an input.

Comment: @ianhales yeah it worked but it gives array as it is.. like Array([0] => php, [1] => jquery, ...). but not able to get array as array.

Comment: I think you need to do `echo implode("\n", $arr);` in your PHP. This will take your array of words, and output a string with each word on a new-line, as per the website I listed above :)

Comment: @ianhales yeah i did that and it worked fine, thank u, and one more thing how can i make autocomplete to show all the matching keywords, like if i have selected PHP and my list has PHP, PHP Framework, PHP 5, then it should show all the 3 options. now the autocomplete function filters the data array which is coming from the server.

Comment: So, your PHP is giving out (e.g.) PHP,PHP Framework,PHP 5? There's an option called "max" which specifies the maximum number (default is 10). If you've got more than 10 and wish to show them all you'll have to set that:
`$('textbox#textboxID').autocomplete( completeData, {max : 99} )`.
 From what I can see, that's the only thing that could be limiting it.

Comment: @ianhales i want to get rid of the filter that is provided by the autocomplete function and load all the data coming from the backend as suggestions. like example i want to query for p then my backend returns all the possible matchs for p in database(that are php,ph,python,p,cakephp, pear). this array is returned from the backend script, and should be loaded. like i want to give user suggestions and not filtered text.

Comment: In which case, I think you want to use:
`$('textbox#textboxID').autocomplete( completeData, {matchContains : true} )`, which searches inside each word instead of just matching the first letters

Comment: @ianhales yeah i have set property {matchContains : true}, its working fine.. but i want to just the hack the sorting provided by the autocomplete function, i.e want only the feature to populate the element with the data comming from the backend, like in the previous example, if p is typed it will get me php,python,p,pear,jqueryplugin... it should load all the array, instead of sorting from the given array... is there any hack for that..

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to set `cacheLength` to 1, that should mean it only uses results it's just pulled from your PHP script, rather than building up a list.
If that doesn't work, have a look through here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions
Those are the options that autocomplete allows.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the parameter you recieve in your PHP script has the key "q" (i.e. `$search = $_GET['q'];`)

See http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions for details.

Comment: yeah it worked, it sends a JSON back from the server but cannot populate the autocomplete element.